# Mongodb count results grouped by date range

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have documents like these:

```
{name: 'doc1', date: "2015-01-01T02:00:12+01:00"},
{name: 'doc2', date: "2015-01-01T03:02:12+01:00"},
{name: 'doc3', date: "2015-01-01T02:17:55+01:00"}
```

Is it possible to count them by time-intervals (for example: 15 minutes) and get result like this:

```
{startDate: "2015-01-01T02:00:12+01:00", count: 15},
{startDate: "2015-01-01T02:15:12+01:00", count: 11},
{startDate: "2015-01-01T02:30:12+01:00", count: 21},
...`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't get an "actual" date object returned this way but you can get a timestamp value which can be used to construct a date object. I'ts just a simple matter of date math:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": 
        "_id": {
            "$subtract": [
                { "$subtract": [ "$date", new Date("1970-01-01") ] },
                { "$mod": [
                    { "$subtract": [ "$date", new Date("1970-01-01") ] },
                    1000 * 60 * 15
                ]}
            ]
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

Subtracting a "date object" with the epoch date will result in the current timestamp value as a number. The basic math is the difference from the modulo at a 15 minute interval ( 1000 milis * 60 secs * 15 minutes ).

If you prefer there are actually [Date Aggregation Operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) which can split up the date as well. Same case is that these are numbers and not a date, but you can re-construct a date object from the values there.

```js
db.collection.aggregation([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "year": { "$year": "$date" },
            "month": { "$month": "$date" },
            "dayOfMonth": { "$dayOfMonth": "$date" },
            "hour": { "$hour" },
            "minute": {
                "$subtract": [
                    { "$minute": "$date" },
                    { "$mod": [
                        { "$minute": "$date" },
                        15    
                    ]}
                ]
            }
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

Comment: In the question, dates are in string and aggregation via Date() wont help it, anyway nice answer

Comment: There are ISODates. Thank you!

Comment: @Disposer if it's a fully formatted string in the response I find it reasonable to say that the actual storage is a date object and we're just being shown the serialized form ( my guess here, from Java IDE ). Anything short or not clearly in ISO format, i.e "2014-01-12" ( could actually mean "2014-12-01" ) needs to be questioned.

Comment: @Neil-Lunn, always  one step ahead of me ;)